# Largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 or 2147483647?

Tags: java

As per [JLS §3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10)

> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648.

Can this statement be considered as true because `Integer.MAX_VALUE` is `2147483647`?

Please note that emphasis in above statement is on "int". If it is argued that it is being talked in context of "decimal literal" then even  `2147483649` and so on, should be also true.

So, if something is of type `int` then its largest value has to be `2147483647`.

Am I getting it wrong or that statement should be updated?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but it seems that the two short paragraphs that follows your quote clarify this issue. From the same section in JLS: **It is a compile-time error if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator; or if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (231).**

Comment: @alfasin But would that make this statement valid, I doubt? My question on this statement, if in this statement "unary minus operator" was even talked then I could understand. So, its clearly ambiguous.

Comment: Now you're taking things out of their context... the section should be read as a whole, the fact that a sentence ends doesn't mean that the context does as well. Reading the following sentence clarifies that while `2147483648` is the largest decimal literal - it is only valid if minus operator precedes it.

Comment: @alfasin Just for building up the context, an incorrect statement cannot be made.

Comment: This statement is not incorrect. 2147483648 *is* a valid int when it's used with the unary minus operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that there are no negative integral literals and `Integer.MIN_VALUE` is −2147483648. So `-2147483648` is parsed as “apply unary minus to 2147483648”.  It would be very bad if 2147483648 would not be a valid decimal `int` literal or you couldn't use an `int` literal of value `Integer.MIN_VALUE` directly in your program.

Side note: The JLS *defines* what is correct. So it is correct by definition.  It can be bad, though.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Clearly that statement is not talking about `-2147483648`, I am concerned about validity of that statement.

Comment: "Clearly that statement is not talking about -2147483648" - I think you're wrong. Please continue reading from the point you stopped quoting the JLS

Comment: @alfasin I have read and understood what was intended, but my question is on validity of that statement. It is ambiguous.

Comment: Your answer is most convincing and hitting bull's eye. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the same [JLS section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1-710)

> The decimal literal 2147483648 may appear only as the operand of the unary minus operator

i.e

int value = -2147483648;

exists

but

int value = 2147483648;

is a compile time error.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Clearly that statement is not talking about `-2147483648`, I am concerned about validity of that statement.

Comment: that statement is only referring to `2147483648` in absolute terms but that can only exist as unary negative value...:)

Answer (score 1):

Every literal is of a specific type of literal (boolean literal, integer literal, floating point literal, etc), although it may be assigned to a field/variable of different type. For example, `2147483647` is a valid integer literal, while `2147999999` is not (while `2147999999L` *is*, although it is a long literal). While the writing is unclear there appears to be no contradiction of any sort.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. But I am concerned about validity of that statement, that's statement is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Reimeus [has the right answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33059650/773113) above.

---

Yep, you are right, the JLS says

> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2^31)

but if you try to compile

```
    int j = 2147483648;
```

you get

```
    Error:(20, 17) java: integer number too large: 2147483648
```

2^31 is equal to 2147483648, which is 0x80000000, but in 32 bit two's complement notation this is actually equal to -1.

So, 2^31 cannot be represented in an int.

An int can only represent values from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which is -2^31, to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, which is (2^31)-1.  And luckily the compiler does not accept integer literals outside of that range.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. Yes I am concerned about validity of that statement.

Comment: But according to the JLS, this should work: `int j = 2147483648--;`

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede No, it does not.  The only thing that works is `int j = -2147483648;`

Comment: @MikeNakis Ah, you're right.  I read "unary minus" as unary decrement instead of unary negation.